# Extra numbers being added when decrementing value from number with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to decrement "0.01" from a number, it works fine the first time, but when I try to decrement one more time it adds some extra numbers.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function decrement() {

        var credits_sidebar = $('#credits_sidebar').html();
        var credits_update = credits_sidebar - 0.01;
        $("#credits_sidebar").fadeOut('');
        $("#credits_sidebar").html(credits_update);
        $("#credits_sidebar").fadeIn(''); 

}
```

If you click once on the decrement button it works, but if you click another time, the number will be `"95.97999999999999"` it should be `95.98` instead.

Here's an example JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rozvnay1/

Answer (score 2):

```
var credits_update = (credits_sidebar - 0.01).toFixed(2)
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8eakhn4L/1/**

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with floating point value representation.
You should consider using

Math.round((credits_sidebar - 0.01)* 100)) / 100

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal and expected because of the way floating point math is done in JavaScript.

However what you simply can do is multiply your number by a factor of 100 to make it a whole number that needs to be decremented then you can do the decrement and divide the result by 100 to get the correct decimal answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update this for working of code:

```
var credits_update = (credits_sidebar - 0.01).toFixed(2);
```